# bad or inaccessible location specified in external data source (null)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm trying to do bulk insert using statement below the path specified in query is actually on  other server. I checked path is correct by manually checking letter by letter, also directly opened in notepad++.

I'm running this query on a remote SQL Server instance

can someone please suggest what could be the reason?

```
BULK INSERT tbl_sample 
FROM '\\AppServer\folder1\folder2\somefile.csv' 
WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' ROWTERMINATOR = '\N' FIRSTROW = 2)
```

> Error: bad or inaccessible location specified in external data source (null)

**Update: We Dropped Bulk insert approach!**

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118546/bad-or-inaccessible-location-specified-in-external-data-source-null

Comment: @SeanLange No, he had issue with file location, I have checked twice I don't have any location related issue. Thanks

Comment: Yes I think you do have path issues. If the path you are providing is intended to reference a network share / UNC path, it is not properly formatted. Are you attempting to load a file that exists somewhere in your (local) machine?

Comment: @SMor No I'm trying load file that on remote server, I'm running this query on instance of same remote server and also I tried to replace servername with remote desktop path. ex: BULK INSERT tbl_sample 
FROM 'F:\folder1\folder2\somefile.csv' 
WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' ROWTERMINATOR = '\N' FIRSTROW = 2). but still doesn't work.

Comment: @SMor and error is: > cannot bulk load becasue the file "F:\folder1\folder2\somefile.csv" could not be opened. operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Is `F:\folder1\folder2\somefile.csv` a file that exists on the SQL Server itself? It can't just reach into your client computer's file system, nor into another server's file system. The account under which the SQL Server instance executes also needs file system permissions granting it access to that file and its parent folder(s).

Comment: If folder1 is a share on AppServer, then use "'\\AppServer\folder1\folder2\somefile.csv'".  If the file is on the sql server, then the F:\folder1\folder2\somefile.csv path is okay.  In either case, the SQL Server service account will need access to the share/file.  If you connect remotely to the SQL Server to run the bulk load query and SQL Server grabs the file on a 3rd machine (e.g. the share), you will encounter a "double hop".  It takes very sensitive permission to permit a server to delegate to a second hop.  If running a job on SQL Server, it can get the file without a second hop.

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysLearning and Randy in Marin